# Unity3D 5 Personal?

Tags: unity

I want to make a game in Unity3D and I am planning to launch it to Android using the free license. However, if the game becomes a huge success and earns more than $100k, does (a) unity take the money for the pro license by themselves? or (b) do I need to pay for pro license myself? If (b) is applicable, how do I upgrade to the pro license and make sure my app is integrated with the pro license not the free version?

Answer (score 1):

http://unity3d.com/unity/faq

> **What happens if I/we make a game with Unity Personal Edition that earns more than $100,000?**
>
> To continue using Unity you would have to purchase a Unity 5 Professional Edition license, which you can do in the Online Store or through your regional Unity sales representative.